# Can't use Jruby with Rbenv on Snow-Leopard

Tags: jruby, osx-snow-leopard, rbenv

I just installed jruby using the ruby-build plugin for rbenv.

```
> rbenv install jruby-1.6.7
Downloading jruby-1.6.7.tar.gz...
-> http://cloud.github.com/downloads/sstephenson/ruby-build-download-mirror/fd1b8d7389aa92da69ea6efb4782e40a
Installing jruby-1.6.7...
Installed jruby-1.6.7
```

Then set my ruby version to jruby

```
> rbenv local jruby-1.6.7
```

Then try to do something with jruby

```
> jruby
```

or

```
> gem list
```

I keep getting back:

```
execv failed: Permission denied (13)
```

The Jruby binary and Java are both executable.
My Java Version:

```
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-10M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2):

I added the following to my .zshrc

```
export JAVACMD=`which java`
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont quote me on this, but it worked for me.

I had been using https://github.com/flatland/drip which I had installed brew on osx snow leopard.

**Warning first**: run `echo $JAVACMD && echo $JAVA_HOME` 
and save what those are in case you need them

When I uninstalled drip with brew I was getting the same error... I ran.

`unset JAVA_HOME`

and

`unset JAVACMD`

and I was back in business